# Accessible program while running a loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, runtime

I want to run a Loop (Do,For ....) but I want the program to be accessible even when that loop is running. An example of what i mean is , that I want the program to run the loop but still ,while running the loop, be able to click anything in my form or to reposition my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a lot of people will say this is bad, evil and ugly, this will help you for your problem:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Application.DoEvents
```

An additional link (explaining, that DoEvents is NOT evil):

http://blog.codinghorror.com/is-doevents-evil/

But, there are obstacles: If you have a long running loop (let´s say a query to a database processing a lot of records) and you want to cancle this, you should disable all "dangerous" buttons while running your loop, that is, disable all others then "cancel". And of course, the cancel button should only be enabled at the beginning of your loop and disabled at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did help , but is it possible to have my loop running while having my events executed without having them to stop one another ????

Comment: To your question: What is happening in the events? Only to move the window or check an Cancel button ok, but If you really need parallel execution, you should start with threading. And be warned, that´s not funny.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim th as new System.Threading.Thread(sub()
                                         'Run Loop here
                                      End Sub)
th.Start()
```

I use the above code a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look to multithreading and asynchronous programming for these kind of issue.

Comment: There are easy "chapter" in multithreading like the Backgroundworker component.